# Snipcart - error: 'product-crawling-failed'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, snipcart

I'm trying to set up Snipcart for the first time. It seems pretty straightforward for the most part, but I'm running into some issues when I try to check out with the test payment card.

I'm working with just a vanilla front end, and Express on the back. I'm getting the same error every time:

```
A 'cart-confirmation' error occurred in Snipcart.

Reason: 'product-crawling-failed'
```

But the URL it's returning me in my console looks like it should be able to crawl for the product properly: `https://myHerokuApp.herokuapp.com/shop/starry-night`

```
    <button class="snipcart-add-item"
        data-item-id="starry-night"
        data-item-price="79.99"
        data-item-url="/shop/starry-night"
        data-item-description="This is a sweet piece of art."
        data-item-image="img/1.jpg"
        data-item-name="The Starry Night">
        Add to cart
    </button>
```

I'm really confused at to what I'm doing wrong. Is there something I have to do with my express router? I've tried routing something like this just to see what would happen

```js
router.get("/shop/:product", function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({
    "data-item-id": "starry-night",
    "data-item-price": "79.99",
    "data-item-url": "/shop/starry-night"
  })
 });
```

But that didn't make a difference.

I'm really hoping someone can spot what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction in the docs..

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes `data-item-id` and `data-item-price` are used with **HTML crawler** and are defined inside buy-button.

If you want to use **JSON crawler**, then you should return valid JSON with properties `id` and `price`. Also, `price` should be of type **number**. Change your backed like this:

```js
router.get("/shop/:product", function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({
    "id": "starry-night",
    "price": 79.99
  })
});
```

**Note:** your server must be publicly available (not running in your localhost).

Comment: thank you :) i was able to solve it with your help